# How can I allow access to SSH only at a specific time?

Tags: 18.04, server, ssh, openssh

Based on Ubuntu 18.04,

I want to allow users to access only from 9 a.m. to 5 p.m.(*working time*) on the SSH server. (used `OpenSSH-server` package)

I've looked up all the materials I think will help you from user management to PAM settings on Google, but I don't think there's any information to restrict access by SSH time zone.

(But, I have not to use firewall-related services like `ufw`.)

If you can help me, please let me know. Thank you.

*(Please understand that my English can be unnatural because I am not good at English.)*

Comment: Do you just want to prevent users from connecting during those hours, or do you want to disconnect already-connected users?

Comment: @steeldriver I just wanted to prevent users from connecting to SSH service from 5 p.m. to 9 a.m. (not working time). Literally.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a cron job to stop and start the ssh server at specific times. For example create a file `/etc/cron.d/start-stop-ssh` with the following contents:

```
0 9 * * * root /usr/sbin/service ssh start
0 17 * * * root /usr/sbin/service ssh stop
```

This will start the ssh service everyday at 9:00 and stop it everyday at 17:00.

Please note that when the service is stopped nobody (even admin) will be able to login via ssh.

Comment: Thank you. I'll try that method.

Answer (score 6):

The `pam_time` module is designed for this.

1. Add `pam_time` as the first `account` statement in the ssh pam config.  This command will insert the statement `account required pam_time.so` just above the line `@include common-account`.

```
sed -i -e '/^.include common-account/i account required pam_time.so' /etc/pam.d/sshd
```

2. configure `/etc/security/time.conf` as desired.  This command will add the configuration `sshd;*;*;Wk0900-1700`.  This limits ssh connections for all users to weekdays between 9am and 5pm.

```
echo 'sshd;*;*;Wk0900-1700' >> /etc/security/time.conf
```

See Also

- http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/en/man8/pam_time.8.html
- http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/en/man5/time.conf.5.html

Comment: Oh, thanks! I learned a new thing. (I'll try that, too!)